# How do I read/import text from a file on the computer to a String? (Java)

Tags: java, string, file, text, import

How do I read/import text from a file on the computer to a String?

The location of the file will be entered by the user via dialog box. I've figured this out, but I have forgotten how to import txt files, into Strings...

I just want to see a coded example from someone on here. Not links.

I'm new, and I learn quicker by looking at code snippits on this site. I have read most of the google search turn-ups.

Thank you! Sorry for bothering everyone...

Comment: When you forget something, google it (or something similar). Why go directly to stackoverflow?

Comment: Another hint: Guava (http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has a method to do this in one line :)

Comment: I did try googling it. Things were too complicated, and everyone had different methods of accomplishing this. The most common was using try{} with IOException catches. Some used scanners, others used buffers. I just need to see some code that moves the text from a text file into a String to be run through algorithms... I need to see code that does this, and only this, instead of a hundred other things with unnecessary information for a beginner to learn...

Comment: Scanner sounds fine to me.

Comment: There are many ways you can do it, and you haven't provide enough information to say what is best.  If you have used Scanner before, you could use that again.

Answer (score 1):

found this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

after 20 seconds of using google.

Comment: I am drinking coffee, so I didn't hurry :)

Comment: I had found this before... I just wanted to see a coded example from someone on here... Thank you for your time...